# Parsing a HTML structure

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Below is my html structure (table):

```xml
<table>
    <tr><td>A</td></tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr><td>B</td></tr>
</table>
<table>
    <table>
        <table>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="A">
                        <td>
                            ABC
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="abc.com">Link</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="B">
                        <td>
                            DEF
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="abcd.com">Link2</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </table>
    </table>
</table>
```

I tried to get data as below:

```
HtmlNode thediv = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[3]//table[1]");
```

⇒ It works well.

But, I tried with code as below to get data ABC/DEF in table 3.

```
 HtmlNode thediv = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(
                       "//table[3]//table[1]//table[2]//table[3]");
```

⇒ Not OK.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you actually want is

```
var bothNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[3]//table[1]//tr/td[1]/text()");
```

That will give you both nodes `ABC` and `DEF` of the third table

You can try it here: [XPathFiddle](http://xpathfiddle.net/PS7YHZ)

Your code doesn't work because there is no node that fits the second query. 
Step by Step:

This is your original html:

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>A</td></tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr><td>B</td></tr>
</table>
<table>
    <table>
        <table>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="A">
                        <td>
                            ABC
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="abc.com">Link</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="B">
                        <td>
                            DEF
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="abcd.com">Link2</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </table>
    </table>
</table>
```

`//table[3]` gives you the third table

```html
<table>
    <table>
        <table>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="A">
                        <td>
                            ABC
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="abc.com">Link</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="B">
                        <td>
                            DEF
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="abcd.com">Link2</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </table>
    </table>
</table>
```

`//table[3]//table[1]` gives you the first table that's a descendant of the third table.

```html
<table>
    <table>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="A">
                    <td>
                        ABC
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="abc.com">Link</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="B">
                    <td>
                        DEF
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="abcd.com">Link2</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </table>
</table>
```

`//table[3]//table[1]//table[2]` would give you the second table that's a descendant the first table that's a descendant of the third table. And there is only one --> doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Manfred Radlwimmer,
Thank for your answer. I did it :).

Answer (score 0):

Hi Manfred Radlwimmer,

Thank for your answer. I did it :).

The code is below:

```
if (doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table") != null)
            {
                HtmlNode thediv = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[3]//table[1]//tr/td[1]//tr[3]//table//tr/td[2]//table");
                HtmlNodeCollection cells = thediv.SelectNodes("tr");
                for (var j = 1; j < cells.Count; ++j)
                {
                    var data= cells[j].InnerText;
                }
            }
```